# Redirect specific path to a different domain (ASP.NET + IIS)

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a set of public API endpoints hosted with our main web app. They are all under the path /api/v1/. I want to move all API calls to a different domain, and keep the original path.

For example, a call to:

```
https://mydoamin.com/api/v1/client/123
```

Should be redirected to:

```
https://api.mydomain.com/api/v1/client/123
```

What's the best way to do this with ASP.NET (Framework 4.8) and IIS?

Note that I have other paths that I don't want to be redirected, like /api/orders. The URL needs to have /api/v1/.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module Use the examples to learn how to write URL rewrite rules. For your case, the rule needs a condition to verify HTTP Host header is `mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iis url rewrite to redirect your url, you can use this rule as a reference:

```
<rule name="test">
  <match url="^api/v1/(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydoamin.com$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://api.mydomain.com/api/v1/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```